# select max group by without id for join

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have table like this :

```
id  name     value
1   roger     43
2   phil      12
3   zac       14
4   phil      42
5   maurice   450
```

...

and i'm trying to retrieve the max value for each name **in order to do a join later**.

I'm expecting the intermediate result to be something like this :

```
   name     value
   roger     43
   zac       14
   phil      42
   maurice   450
```

And this is easily achieved using and `select name,max(value) from table group by name`

My issue is that i NEED the id in order to later be able to do my join. but if i add my id to the aggregate/ group by it will mess up the result and will show all values since the id will be different.

So the true expect result is more like this :

```
 id name     value
 1  roger     43
 3  zac       14
 4  phil      42
 5  maurice   450
```

I have seen many question regarding similar issues but none where the id need to be retrieved but not included in the group by since i want uniqness for the name and only need the id for my join.

Comment: I have no idea where the `42` comes form for `phil`.

Comment: My guess is a typo from `12`

Comment: I think it is a typo from 15, that is the max value.

Comment: yes i'm sorry that was indeed a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `not exists`:

```
select min(t.id) id, t.name, t.value 
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where name = t.name and value > t.value
)
group by t.name, t.value
order by id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5VWHHKeVYQ5wFzhA4HQa6h/4).
Results:

```
| id  | name    | value |
| --- | ------- | ----- |
| 1   | roger   | 43    |
| 3   | zac     | 14    |
| 4   | phil    | 42    |
| 5   | maurice | 450   |
```

Comment: That's seems to be working expect for the case where value would equal t.value. Would  `select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where (name = t.name and value > t.value) or (name = t.name and value = t.value)
)` work ?

Comment: If there are 2 rows having the maximum value for the same name then they will be both returned. Do you want something different?

Comment: Yes i want something different , only return 1 row per name for all names, never 2+ rows. I'm just worried about the case where both row would have the same value i would need to pick either row in that case.

Comment: See my edited answer. It returns the minimum id in case there are 2 rows with the same name and the same maximum value. You can change it to return the maximum id.

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe, you just want the max of `id`:

```
select max(id) as id, name, max(value)
from table
group by name;
```

Or, what I think you want is the row with the max value:

```
select distinct on (name) t.*
from t
order by name, value desc;
```

Comment: I had a typo in there. What i want is the max value for "name" while still keeping the id of the max value in there so it can be used later for the join.

Comment: @user7952151 . . . That is the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH X (n, v) AS (
  SELECT name, MAX(value) FROM tbl GROUP BY name
)
SELECT T.*
FROM tbl AS T INNER JOIN X ON T.name = X.n AND T.value = X.v
```

Comment: You should take into account the fact that there may be more than 1 records qith the same name and value but with different id.

Comment: indeed there is duplicate names and duplicate values